# updating sql table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, sql-update

Whenever i tried to update the form using following code, the update goes silent with the 0 value in title field and previous value in content field. Can someone please help!!!

## adminClass.php

### update function

```
 if( $form_title && $form_content ){
       $sql = "UPDATE home_page
       SET title = '{$form_title}' AND content = '{$form_content}' WHERE id = {$id}";
       echo $sql;
       $result = $this->mysqli->query( $sql );
       if(!$result){
         echo 'Error'. mysqli_error();
         return;
       }else{
         $this->success_message = "Update Successfull";
         return;
       }
    }
```

## admin.php view page

```
if( isset( $_POST['update'] ) ){
   $admin_obj->update($_POST, $id);
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL silently cast your `UPDATE` statement and performs boolean operation.
The server reads the update statement as

```
UPDATE home_page
SET title = ('{$form_title}' AND (content = '{$form_content}')) 
WHERE id = {$id}
```

What you are going to do is to replace the `AND` into `,` to make it work.

```
UPDATE home_page
SET title = '{$form_title}', content = '{$form_content}'
WHERE id = {$id}
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)